# How can I keep the style of images which wrapped in <a> tags

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I have 9 images in a flex display, when they are not wrapped in <a> tags, they look good.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzpj8.png)

However, I wanna make these images as clickable. So I wrapped them in <a> tags, however, the format changed to this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWuDc.png)

The code is:

```
<div class="nine-products-section">
  <button class="pre-btn">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/arrow.png"}}" alt="">
  </button>
  <button class="nxt-btn">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/arrow.png"}}" alt="">
  </button>
  <div class="product-container">
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Ana_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}" alt=""
      class="product-image">
    </a>
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener class="
      product-link=""
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Logan_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}" alt=""
      class="product-image"></a
    >
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Hugh_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}" alt=""
      class="product-image">
    </a>
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Miles_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}" alt=""
      class="product-image">
    </a>
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Rae_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}" alt=""
      class="product-image"></a
    >
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Stella_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}"
      alt="" class="product-image">
    </a>
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Peggy_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}" alt=""
      class="product-image"></a
    >
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
    >
      <img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Serge2_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}"
      alt="" class="product-image">
    </a>
    <a
      href="xxxx"
      rel="noopener"
      class="product-link"
      ><img src="{{media
      url="wysiwyg/Round-face-test/Wilder_Product_Block_3x_622x233.jpg"}}"
      alt="" class="product-image"></a
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.nine-products-section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.product-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.product-image {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I tried to style the <a> tag, height/ padding/ width. but they all did not work. How can I make these images keep the old style but clickable to redirect to the links?

Comment: It's hard to say without a demo. Please add one

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by adding:

```css
a {
    display: contents;
}
```

in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

1. wrap  tag with div
2. delete .product-image css code, if needed, add it on  tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).